# Using an Apps Script library in a webapp html file?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, libraries

I'm just starting to use libraries in Apps Script.  I can get libraries to work when the library code is referenced from a .GS file but the I cannot get libraries to work when accessing them via .HTML files (I get a message xxx is undefined)

Before I spend anymore time on this can anyone confirm that libraries are only for .GS files

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call library functions directly, but if you create a function that calls library functions on the Google Apps Script side,

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler (onSuccess) .gasfunction ()
```

Can be called with

There are various uses.

**Reference links:[Library functions cannot be called directly](https://officeforest.org/wp/2018/11/29/google-apps-script%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%83%96%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80/#i-12)**

Comment: Great, thank you.  That has saved me hours of testing and scratching my head.   I'll try that and see what the performance deficit is versus keeping the actual code in the .HTML  if it's not much deficit it my be worth this approach for the saving in maintenance across the 20 scripts that use the library.

Answer (score 0):

Html libraries are different from  server script libraries.  There is no point in using server side library in html. Even if it is defined, it'll be useless. You could however call the server library from html(client side) through [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)